# Help my identify this bike. (3Rensho? Specialized Allez?)

Tags: identify-this-bike

Help my identify this bike.
Looks like a 3Rensho or early Specialized Allez but can't find any bikes with same features.
Any info on brand/years, possibly frame size would be welcome.

[image: frame]

[image: fork]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sun Tour Pro rear drop outs - any markings on the fork drop out or headset? What parts did it come with?

Comment: Lugged steel frame with braze-ons for downtube shifters and a six(?)-speed freewheel says mid-late 1980s to me. SunTour Pro says Japanese, not Italian/English/French. Internal cable guides could be Miyata or Nishiki, as in this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/bicycling/comments/15crpv/new_bike_1985_nishiki_tria_wcomplete_internal/

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but you can measure the frame size yourself with a measuring tape.

[image]

Its not exact, but you'll see to within a centimetre or so.  Road frames normally came in steps of 2cm or half an inch, and sometimes came in 1cm increments for top-end bikes.

Other measurements like top tube length can be measured by starting in the middle of the butting tube.

Comment: That is a loverly frame - will be a nice bike when you've finished it.

Comment: I don't think it's an Allez--I don't think Specialized used internal cables or Cinelli-style fastback seatstays on those. Although I was surprised to learn that [Konno built some Allez for Specialized](http://vintage3rensholove.blogspot.com/2011/01/specialized-allez-3rensho-built.html), and the lugwork is very similar. He did use fastback seatstays on some 3Rensho bikes.

Comment: @AdamRice I have no idea what it is - this partial-answer only addresses the "how to measure the frame size" part of OP's question